# How to use date_detection and numeric_detection in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring data elasticsearch. I have a business requirement to use date_detection:false and numeric_detection:false to disable auto date and numeric detection by elasticsearch.

Can some one please help or instruct how to use date_detection:false and numeric_detection:false in spring data elasticsearch?